# ASP.NET 5.0 Kestrel server with nginx

Tags: c#, asp.net, nginx, asp.net-core

I am trying to host an ASP.NET 5.0 (beta 4) website on Ubuntu. I have configured Kestrel with nginx as a reverse proxy, but there are a couple of problems that prevent this from being used for a production site:

- HTTP 404 error pages are blank - is there a way to configure either ASP.NET/Kestrel or nginx to send a custom page instead of a blank page?
- How can I configure URL rewriting - for example, I have some static .htm pages in addition to the ASP.NET content, and I would like to rewrite these to serve them without the .htm extension

Comment: For both of your issues, I highly recommend looking into "ASP.NET 5 Middleware" and the `Run` options off of `IApplicationBuilder`. There isn't a way out of the box to do what you're asking for either option (just like a node connect server), though samples could be provided if they were separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from Matt DeKrey, I got this working using two pieces of middleware.

For custom 404 error pages, I used:

```
public class CustomErrorMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public CustomErrorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        await context.Response.SendFileAsync("/errors/404.html");
    }
}
```

While for URL rewriting I used:

```
public class UrlRewriteMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public UrlRewriteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Redirect from /some/page.htm to /some/page
        Regex r1 = new Regex("^/some/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.htm$");
        if (r1.IsMatch(context.Request.Path.Value))
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.Path.Value.Substring(0, context.Request.Path.Value.Length - 4));
            return;
        }

        // Rewrite from /some/page to /some/page.htm
        Regex r2 = new Regex("^/some/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        if (r2.IsMatch(context.Request.Path.Value))
            context.Request.Path = new PathString(context.Request.Path.Value + ".htm");

        await next(context);
    }
}
```

Then `Startup.cs` is modified to use each of these. Middleware is run in the order it is specified in, so the URL rewriting needs to be first to modify the requests as they are received. The custom 404 error middleware needs to be last to catch any requests not handled by any other middleware. For example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<UrlRewriteMiddleware>();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseMiddleware<CustomErrorMiddleware>();
}
```